# append function appends previous data with the new data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following data from ajax which I am trying to display in a UI's popup :

```html
[{"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/1.png"},

{"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/beyond.png"},

{"BadgeImage":"http:\/\/localhost:8666\/web1\/profile\/images\/badge image 2\/completionist.png"}]
```

I am using the below Jquery to display it in the popup :

```js
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  var $img = $('<img src="' + data[index].BadgeImage + '"/>'); // create the image
  $img.addClass('badge-image'); // add the class .badge-image to it

  $('#imagesofBadges').append($img); // append it
  $('#imagesofBadges .badge-image'); // will fetch all the elements that have the class .badge-image that are inside #imagesofBadges.

});
```

I am able to display the images .

**The problem is everytime I click an element which displays the popup,The images of the previous popup gets appended in the new popup.**

I tried using one() which is present in jquery and also tried using a counter as in below codes ,but no luck.

```js
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  var $img = $('<img src="' + data[index].BadgeImage + '"/>'); // create the image
  $img.addClass('badge-image'); // add the class .badge-image to it
  if (counter <= 0) {
    $('#imagesofBadges').append($img); // append it
    $('#imagesofBadges .badge-image'); // will fetch all the elements that have the class .badge-image that are inside #imagesofBadges.
    counter++;
  }
});
```

please help me on how to display the images, such that it does not get appended to the previous data of the popup.

Comment: Please use the `<>` to add [mcve] including HTML. To just add formatted code, indent 4 spaces or highlight and press  the `{}` button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the previous content of the container, You ca use [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

> Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```
$('#imagesofBadges').empty();
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  //Your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - `.append()` will append previous html with new one, `.html()` will overwrite old html for you

```
 $('#imagesofBadges').html($img);
```

Comment: @Satpal thanks a lot. got mixed with javascript innerhtml and jquery html()

Comment: tried this... in the ajax array , it displays only the last image.For instance,if u look at the above ajax call data,it contains three images.using ur code,it displays only the last image from the ajax data.

Comment: @jane if you are having async call. then you have to append this at callback function